# JDA Discord Bot: INTEGER Option Range

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm working on a Discord bot using JDA (Java Discord API), and I'm having trouble setting up a slash command that includes an INTEGER option with a specific range. Despite going through the official JDA documentation and searching online, I couldn't find a solution that addresses my problem.

Please note that I do not just want to implement a if clause. I want to specifically cause the error seen below.

[image: Image showing a Command where a invalid Number was entered.]

Currently I am implementing a slash command like this:

```java
jda.updateCommands().addCommands(
  Commands.slash("casino", "casino commands.")
    .addSubcommands(
      new SubcommandData("slots", "Play slots in the Casino.")
        .addOption(OptionType.INTEGER, "amount", "the amount of money you want to bet.")
    )
).queue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [addOptions](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/commands/build/SlashCommandData.html#addOptions(java.util.Collection)) to pass in an instance of [OptionData](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/commands/build/OptionData.html) with more configuration.

```java
addOptions(new OptionData(INTEGER, "amount", "...")
  .setRequiredRange(1, 10))
```